# searching text within Html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I just googling to find a script that I can use to find a text within HTML table.

Like I create a table of student names which have many columns and rows. I have a good script too that display whatever I try to search but it display full row...

```js
function searchSname() {
    var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
            found = false;
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input id='myInput' onkeyup='searchSname()' type='text'>

<table id='myTable'>
   <tr>
      <td>AB</td>
      <td>BC</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>CD</td>
      <td>DE</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>EF</td>
      <td>GH</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

But know I am looking for making some changes to display exact text whatever I searched instead of full row like it will display text that I type to search and hide other unmatched fully....

Kindly let me know is it possible to display text only that I type to search within a table? Like if I try to find student name "AB" then it should display AB only instead of "AB BC".

Comment: Why do you not apply another CSS style to the other cells like a diferent color? I think the user can see the other values but, the searched data must be in evidence.

Comment: thats a nice idea but i try to create something hide/display not highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much simpler than you are making it.

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td");
var search = document.getElementById("myInput");

search.addEventListener("keyup", function(){

  for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i){
    // This line checks for an exact match in a cell against what the
    // user entered in the search box
    //if(cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase() === search.value.toLowerCase()){
    
    // This checks for cells that start with what the user has entered
    if(cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value.toLowerCase()) === 0){      
        cells.forEach(function(element){
            element.style.display = "none";
        });
        cells[i].style.background = "yellow";
        cells[i].style.display = "table-cell";
        break;
    } else {
        cells[i].style.background = "white";
        cells.forEach(function(element){
          if(cells[i] !== element){
            element.style.display = "table-cell";
          }
        }); 
    }    
  }

});
```

```css
table, td { border:1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
```

```html
<input id='myInput'>

<table id='myTable'>
   <tr>
      <td>AB</td>
      <td>BC</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>CD</td>
      <td>DE</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>EF</td>
      <td>GH</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```